# Where is memory allocated when the memfd_create syscall is used?

Tags: linux, gdb, system-calls, memory-mapping

According to the manpages for `memfd_create`, when I call `memfd_create` it provides me with a file descriptor that I can read from and write to that corresponds to some space in main memory. My question is where exactly is this memory being allocated? `memfd_create` is a syscall so it isn't using `malloc` to allocate memory in the heap and, using GDB, it doesn't seem like a new page in memory is being created when `memfd_create` is called.

Comment: Did you only call memfd_create or did you actually write using the file descriptor returned from memfd_create?

Comment: I wrote to it with the write() syscall.